# Java Eclipse get an empty input

Tags: java, eclipse, java.util.scanner, user-input

Can we get an empty input with the eclipse console in java? Simply get the "Enter" without any characters?
The way i get the input right now is :

```
import java.util.Scanner;         
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(!userInput.hasNext());

    String input = "";
    if (userInput.hasNext()) input = userInput.nextLine();

    if (input.equals("TheKeyIWant")) 
    {
     //do stuff
    }
```

Right now, I need any entry then press enter. I've looked up the raw consoles but on windows, what i found was unclear so until now i've prefered not to get a raw console. What im trying to get is to not need an entry. Just press enter without anything and the code sees it.

Console Example of what it does vs. what i want:

```
Please enter something:
"Press 4 and enter"
You pressed 4
////////////
Please enter something:
"Press enter"
You pressed nothing
```

Feel free to ask any more clarifications or to propose ideas. I haven't coded that much in java so maybe there's stuff i dont know.

Thanks!

Edit: Answering the question if anybody wonders, as @KevinAnderson answered, hasNextLine() gets anything, including blanks as spaces or enters while the hasNext() waits for a token as a character.

Comment: input.equals("") should be nothing

Comment: @PhilippSander Thats what i tought but apparently, the console doesnt even see it. Its not registered by the code as if nothing happened. The while(!userInput.hasNext()); seems to not consider empty entry and loop until there is something. Strangely a "space" isnt considered either. Maybe the eclipse console is set like so or is something in the parameters

Comment: Can you prvide a [mcve], your outputs don't match the code you show ... this is complicated to understand your problem

Comment: It's nothing to do with Eclipse, it's just how `Scanner` works with console input.  Anyway, try `hasNextLine()` to check if user has pressed Enter.  `hasNext()` waits for a "token", which is pretty much anything **except for** Enter, spaces, tabs, and all other "white space".

Comment: @KevinAnderson You sir are a genius. hasNextLine() works exactly how i needed it to. I cannot thank you enough!